# How to make SONY NEX F3 pictures display the date it was taken at the bottom right corner?

Tags: sony, display

Is there a way to make SONY NEX F3 pictures display the date it was taken?

Comment: Do you want this displayed on the camera LCD, temporarily as you are reviewing them, or to be actually written visibly on to the photos for printing or sharing?

Comment: This is definitely something you should find out from the manual. Look for anything that says *Date* in the table of contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the camera [manual](http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/NEX-F3/manuals), Sony NEX F3 does not have a feature for superimposing dates on images. By using “PlayMemories Home” on the CD-ROM (supplied), you can print or save images with the date.

Answer (score 1):

[NOTE: When I first answered this, I was thinking NEX-3 rather than NEX-F3, so the information about available controls is likely not the same. I will leave the information for NEX-3 owners, but if you have the NEX-F3 (a much more expensive and capable version of the NEX camera series), my myopic observations may not apply.]

If the pictures are still in the camera:  Press the Play button (the right arrow in a box on top of the camera) to bring up the previews of previous pictures, and rotate the rear control to get to the image you want to check. On the top rim of the dial control on back, press the DISP part of the ring repeatedly to advance through the various display options. One view will have very little printed info on the image, the next view will add in the information about the date, shutter speed, aperture and other EXIF data recorded when you took the picture. The last mode shows histograms of the color channels along with the EXIF data.

If you have already downloaded the pictures: For a Windows system, just right click on the desired image in the directory it was downloaded to and select Properties, then in the Properties window select the Details tab. This will show you the same information that is stored in each JPEG image. Hoping this helps...

Answer (score 0):

-In the software that shipped with the camera, Sony PlayMemories, there is an option to "print date taken" in the print window.

-This can be done using Lightroom, and the post-process plug-in Mogrify 2 (free)

http://photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrmogrify2.php?sec=main

Mogrify 2 allows you to add a watermark to your images, which can include many things, such as the Date from the EXIF image data.

-Finally, search Google for Photoshop scripts, as there many to choose from.

-Many other software packages provide this feature, such as Photoshop Elements, etc.